Drag&Drop Files - But get list of files already during drag
I would like to allow users to drag&drop files from the windows explorer, but already fetch some infos about the files even before the user drops them into the application. E.g., to already fetch some metadata or previews of massive files.
There is a lot of info out there about drag&drop with the WinAPI, but I haven't found anything that allows me to already process the files during drag, without waiting for the drop. Is this possible at all?

Your target implements IDropTarget https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleidl/nn-oleidl-idroptarget so it can get information when DragEnter, DragOver x times, DragLeave an (optionally) Drop methods are called. DragEnter contains an IDataObject arguement interface reference (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-idataobject) that contains all available information

Also see this DragDropVisuals sample.

@YangXiaoPo-MSFT That helped, thanks!

@SimonMourier That helped, thanks!

Promote @SimonMourier 's comment to answer.

Your target implements IDropTarget so it can get
information when DragEnter, DragOver x times, DragLeave an
(optionally) Drop methods are called. DragEnter contains an
IDataObject argument interface reference that contains all available information.

Also see this DragDropVisuals sample.
